# Linebreak in @if block turns into needless whitespace in Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Let's say I have `Index.cshtml`:

```
<div>
    <p>@Html.Partial("Test")←please, no whitespace here</p>
</div>
```

And partial is:

```
@if (true)
{
    <span>true text from partial</span>
}
```

Now, there is a whitespace between last word from partial and `←` from `Index.cshtml`.

I found a few ways to get rid of it, but all of them seem hacky:

1. `<span>true text from partial</span>{return;}`
2. `@(Html.Raw("<span>true text from partial</span>"))`
3. `@if (true){<span>true text from partial</span>}` (just write everything in a single row)

Is there a better one? Am I using something the way it shouldn't be used?

Comment: Are you just passing a bool into the partial?  If so why use a partial? why not just do something like a tertiary: `<p><span>@Html.Raw(Model.IsTrue ? "Some true text" : "Some false text")</span></p>`

Comment: @Pete no, it's not a boolean. In app the whole partial is a DisplayTemplate for our custom `DateTimeOptionalOffset` date type. It renders the date one way or another, depending on if it has Offset in it. tl;dr: I can't inline it because it's (1) not too readable (2) needed in more than one place.

Comment: You might try creating a custom helper instead of a partial

Comment: Well the way razor works is that it will render all the white spaces around any if tags / partials - are you really that bothered that your source code is going to have a little extra white space in it?

Comment: @DanielJ.G. looks like a nice option, will give it a try, thanks

Comment: @Pete well, it's the needless whitespace in html output (between "partial" and "←") which bothers me